# In Azure, how to create Web application which will capture user information mostly a normal Web Form for 300 users and Create Dashboards

Tags: azure-web-app-service

My Requirement is

1. Capture the user information e.g. name, id, email id, etc. which currently Im capturing through the excel sheet by sending the sheet to everyone. I want to automate this in Azure by creating a simple web application.
2. Store the information in a DB or storage.
3. Create Graphs and dashboards. Update the dashboards automatically as and when the informrtaion gets added/updated.
4. Provide users access to the Web application(Front-end) forms only.
5. Allow users to update the information they provided as and when needed.
6. Allow application access using Azure AD

What are the possible simple solutions available in Azure with minimal cost.

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app?pivots=platform-windows which is a quick start tutorial that uses https://github.com/azure-samples/dotnetcore-sqldb-tutorial. It outlines creating an application and storing in an Azure SQL DB. By using .NET Core, you can leverage either Windows or Linux app service plan which opens your options as far as pricing goes. In the repo, you can modify [Todo.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/dotnetcore-sqldb-tutorial/blob/master/Models/Todo.cs) to match your user information requirements.

For allowing application access using Azure AD, have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-windows.

You can get started easily by using a Free tier app service plan and either basic or general [DTU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tiers-dtu) or [v-Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tiers-vcore) Azure SQL Database pricing.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I will check this. Is there any other simple way or ready SaaS service available in azure? Or similar to google forms are there azure forms available.

Comment: If your organization uses Microsoft 365 subscription, then you could use [Microsoft Forms](https://forms.office.com/) in conjunction with either [Power Apps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/) or [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) to capture responses and save them to an Azure SQL Server.